# Kubernetes Ingress configuration rewrite problem

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm creating a configuration to host some apps in a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. I have two different apps, with separate service/pod/selector but I want to expose them with a single ingress for the moment.

So I created the following ingress controller

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: bar
          servicePort: 8080
```

and the ingress obtain the ELB from AWS without any problem, but when I try to browse the app (Java application using Tomcat appserver) I always receive the following page

[image: Tomcat]

It's the classic old Tomcat welcome page but every request always returns the index.html (no css/img loaded) and also if I try to use the correct context path for the application I receive this page.

If I expose the apps using a Service (LoadBalancer) I can use it without these problems, so I think there is something wrong with ingress configuration.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE

If I use an ingress with a single path like this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 8080
```

Using INGRESSHOST url I can see the Tomcat home with img/css and if I browse to INGRESSHOST/APPCONTEXT I can use the app without problem

Comment: check your browser network log from what url it tries to fetch the resources.

Comment: the only right request is the main page, the other requests aren't rewritten correctly. the index.html img/css aren't loaded because they use a relative path

Comment: would the services when accessed directly respond on the root path?

Comment: the app replies to its context path if directly exposed. if I remove ingress and publish the service as a LoadBalancer everything works. In the ingress configuration if I ask INGRESS_HOST/foo/foocontext I always receive the main Tomcat page (available at INGRESS_HOST/foo). For every request starting with foo I receive Tomcat index page

Comment: first thing: the code you have shared on the top is ingress-resource not controller. maybe it will be good if you have shared controller code also. I assume it is `nginx deployment`...?

Comment: I used stardard configuration for L4 ELB from NGINX website for AWS https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have recently changed the version of your nginx-ingress controller then maybe the cause can be a recent change done to it. Now it uses regex rewrite rules and maybe your rewrite target is just always being rewritten to "/". I think the changes were introduced in version 0.22 in January.

The new correct syntax for your ingress would be:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /bar(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: bar
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: ok if I use this syntax something works, I can see now the Tomcat homepage with everything loaded, so INGRESSHOST/foo/ show Tomcat homepage, but if I try to use INGRESSHOST/foo/myfooapp it redirect me to INGRESSHOST/myfooapp and I receive a 404 default backend from ingress controller.

Comment: @FedericoPaparoni, the redirection is done by your application. The thing with reverse proxies(ingress here acts like one) is that the original path of the request is lost when it reaches the receiving application. So the receiving application actually thinks that the URL of the request is `http://foo/myfooapp` and Redirects the user to an absolute URI starting with `/myfooapp` which is obviously wrong. To properly use an application (with redirections and absolute URL generation) in a setup such as this the application should have an option to set its public URL.

Comment: @FedericoPaparoni alternatively, if you mount the application contexts loaded inside of tomcat in paths matching that of the ingress everything will probably work. Your applications should be accessible then inside the kubernetes cluster on the following URLs: `http://foo/foo/myfooapp` and `http://bar/bar/myfooapp`

In this setup you can also remove the rewrite target annotation.

Comment: I understand the problem, but unfortunately I cannot modify too much the application. Using host (foo.example.com and bar.example.com) the apps work fine and also the sticky session requires the host so I can use it. Anyway thank you for your help with regex update of ingress controller

Comment: It worked after changing - path: /foo(.*) to - path: /foo/(.*), there is "/" added after foo